# File manager for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Often i need compare or edit some files, which are not in the project. For example from the removable drive. I like to work with any files in eclipse(so much power!). But to see files, they must be in any project.

I try to place files into some project - it's not comfortable. I need to open file manager and copy files into existing project or create new project in eclipse.

I try create project with "d:\" location, but it overlaps my existing projects and eclipse can't create such project.

I search through plugins and install EclipseCommander - it's not what i want, because there is no "compare with" in context menu, it have popup, it overrides my controls(when commander view is open(but not in focus) and i press f5 in package explorer, eclipse try to invoke "copy" :) ), etc.

Best if i can browse all my computer's files in tree-like view, like "package explorer", "navigator" or "project explorer".

Till now best what i find is to create project with "e:\" location. But it creates project on e:\ and still not solve problem with files on d:\ .

So how to browse all local files in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create projects, or I recommend instead, folders for each drive. It's a Windows limitation/design that every drive has a separate volume and there's no *real* root to everything on the system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found now option create linked resources. I make project in eclipse workspace and 2 resources - e:\ and c:\. But d:\ i can't add because eclipse says that it's not valid path for linked resource. Do you mean that when say "create folders for each drive" ? Why i can't add d:\ ? On d:\ there is many of my projects. What can i do to add it?

Comment: If you already have projects in the workspace in that location, you shouldn't be able to create another resource that is a parent of that location. Any code or UI going up or down that overlapping tree of directories would infinitely loop and lock up or crash Eclipse.

Comment: Hmm, i have maven project with modules. And i see the same file in two project simultaneously.